# Add nodes into deeper branches of XML tree

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xmlnode

I'm developing a web interface that enables admins to ban/unban particular users from my server whose software depends on an XML file to determine ban status of users. Initially, the 'Bans.xml' has the following contents.

```
    <Bans version="1.036">
      <Nick>
         <Ban>
           <Overrideable enable="false"/>
           <Nick>cray</Nick>
         </Ban>
      </Nick>
    </Bans>
```

How do I write a php code so that I get the following XML file?

```
    <Bans version="1.036">
      <Nick>
         <Ban>
           <Overrideable enable="false"/>
           <Nick>cray</Nick>
         </Ban>
         <Ban>
           <Overrideable enable="false"/>
           <Nick>newuser</Nick>
         </Ban>
      </Nick>
    </Bans>
```

So far I've managed to write the following script:

```
    <?php
      $xml=new DOMDocument();
      $xml->formatOutput=true;
      $xml->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
      $xml->load("Bans.xml");
      $root=$xml->documentElement;
      $fnode=$root->firstChild;
      $ori=$fnode->childNodes->item(2);
      $nick=$xml->createElement("Nick");
      $nickText=$xml->createTextNode("newuser");
      $nick->appendChild($nickText);
      $ban=$xml->createElement("Ban");
      $ban->appendChild($nick);
      $root->insertBefore($ban,$ori);
      header("Content-type:text/xml");
      $xml->save('Bans.xml');    
     ?>
```

But all that the above code gives me is:

```
    <Bans version="1.036">
      <Nick>
        <Ban>
          <Overrideable enable="false"/>
          <Nick>cray</Nick>
        </Ban>
      </Nick>
      <Ban>
        <Nick>Crayaas</Nick>
      </Ban>
    </Bans>
```

--------I've managed to add the nodes properly by replacing;---------

```
    $root->insertBefore($ban,$ori);
```

With the following code;

```
    $fnode->insertBefore($ban,$ori);
```

My one last question is, how do i remove a particular ban, where nick is equal to a user supplied string stored in the variable $buser. I used the following code. But using $buser in the condition creates errors.

```
    $buser="newuser";                
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('settings/Bans.xml');
    $bans=$dom->documentElement;
    $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
    $result=$xpath->query('/Bans/Nick/Ban[Nick="$buser"]');
    $result->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($result->item(0));
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    $dom->save('settings/Bans.xml');
```

Would be glad if this could be answered as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$root->insertBefore($ban,$ori);
```

Should be:

```
$fnode->insertBefore($ban,$ori);
```

After all, `<Nick>` is not the rootnode, but the first child of it

Comment: I had one more doubt. How do i add the element;
        <Overrideable enable="false"/>

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot mate. Your answer really helped solve my problem.

Comment: `$override=$xml->createElement("Overrideable");$override->setAttribute('enabled','false');$ban->appendChild($override);`

Answer (score 1):

You want to append a new subtree like this:

```
 <Ban>
    <Overrideable enable="false"/>
    <Nick>newuser</Nick>
 </Ban>
```

Hence, build that structure and then [appendChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to /Bans/Nick.

On a sidenote, your element naming is somewhat questionable because your element names have different semantics depending on where they occur. While you can do that, I think you could make it less ambiguous by removing /Bans/Nick altogether and just use:

```
<Bans version="1.036">
   <Ban>
      <Overrideable enable="false"/>
      <Nick>cray</Nick>
   </Ban>
</Bans>
```

Then you would simply append to the root element.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yeah, i didn't notice the change in element naming. I don't want to edit my XML tree because, the application that uses this XML file, depends on a particular tree layout to carry out its functions ;)

Comment: @Cray well, even if you keep the layout it's IMO still easier to append the new child nodes instead of using insertBefore.